# ServicePoint.Expect100Continue for Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, windows-8, windows-runtime

As the title says, i need to set this flag to false for my app, like so:

```
 ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```

However neither ServicePoint nor ServicePointManager are accessible, and i can't find another way to set this property. Also, there is no app.config so setting it via configuration is also not possible.

If i do no set this to false, the flag is sent in the request and a CommunicationException occurs.

I cannot change server code, i am only a consumer of server data.

The service is added with the "Add Service Reference" dialog. Any method call results in:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

When i call the same service, added with "Add Service Reference" from a console application, there is the same error. The reason is the Expect100Continue Attribute. If i remove it [using the usual methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/11/05/http-expect-continue-delays-transmitting-post-bodies-by-up-to-350-milliseconds.aspx), it works in the console app.

So, i'd like to know what the equivalent is for Windows Store apps.

Comment: Post all exception and how you sending request.

Comment: @Reniuz i added some more info, but i am pretty sure i know how to solve it technically (setting the property to false) but there is no obvios way to do it in windows store apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking the auto-generated classes from "add service reference" and serializing them myself. I then use HttpClient to make my calls. It is possible to set the ExpectContinue flag there like this:

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
 {
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;

      ....code!
 }
```